# Tikz : drawing a parallelogramm question (summing nodes)

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I'd like to caclculate the coordinates of C knowing A,B,D in the ABCD parallelogramm.

This works fine :

```
\coordinate (C) at ($(B)!.5!(D)!-1!(A)$) ;
```

This doesn't work, why ?

```
\coordinate (C) at ($(B)+(D)-2*(A)$) ;
```

Here a MWE :

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (A) at (5,2) ;
\coordinate (B) at (1,-4) ;
\coordinate (D) at (-5,6) ;

% This doesn't work, why ?
\coordinate (C) at ($(B)+(D)-2*(A)$) ;

\coordinate (C) at ($(B)!.5!(D)!-1!(A)$) ;

\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--cycle ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't just `\coordinate (C) at ($(B)+(D)-(A)$);` what you need?

Comment: Ok I made a mistake with vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to show it visually why and let me know if you need details. `2*==>` denotes the result of the one that doesn't work. `!==>` is the *working* one. Though both of them are working properly as seen from the paths. They are just not equivalent syntax. Especially, `(B)+(D)` is the sum relative to the origin, not to each other.

Hence the one that doesn't work is:

```
 (1,-4) + (-5,6) - (10,4) = (-14,-2)
```

that matches the text I've put in the node. Hence the matching calculation is

```
(B) + (D) - (A)
```

without the `2*`

Nevermind the `pt`s they are the cm equivalents but I was too lazy to remove them.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every label/.style={font=\Huge}]
\coordinate[label=A] (A) at (5,2) ;
\coordinate[label=B] (B) at (1,-4) ;
\coordinate[label=D] (D) at (-5,6) ;

\draw[blue,thick,->] (0,0) --++(B)--++(D)--++([scale=-1]A)--++ ([scale=-1]A)
let \p1 = ($(B)+(D)-2*(A)$),
      \n1={int(\x1/28.3464567)},
      \n2={int(\y1/28.3464567)} in node[below,font=\Huge]{\texttt{2*==>} \n1,\n2};

\draw[red,ultra thick,->] (0,0) -- ($(B)!0.5!(D)$) -- (A) to[bend right]($(B)!0.5!(D)!-1!(A)$)
let \p1 = ($(B)!.5!(D)!-1!(A)$),
      \n1={int(\x1/28.3464567)},
      \n2={int(\y1/28.3464567)} in node[below right,font=\Huge] {\texttt{!=>}\n1,\n2};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's clearly not the same calculation, I made a mystake with the vertices. Sorry. Should I delete this non sens question ?